# update UISlider progress bar currenttime and duration when audio plays

Tags: iphone, ios6

Have a UISlider ProgressBar on UIToolbar when audio plays wants UISlider ProgressBar to display the duration of the audio file and currenttime of the audio file.

```
 - (void)playAction:(id)sender
 {
if([player isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [player pause];
    //[self pauseTimer];


}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audiopause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [player play];
    //[self resumeTimer];


    }

[self updateProgressBar:timer];

}


- (void)updateProgressBar:(NSTimer *)timer
{
NSTimeInterval playTime = [self.player currentTime];
NSTimeInterval duration = [self.player duration];
float progress = playTime/duration;
[_progressBar setProgress:progress];

}
```

But it is not working.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to call the updateProgressBar method using a timer, rather than what you're doing right now (calling it in the playAction method).  Instead, you can use the playAction method to create the timer that calls updateProgressBar, or pause/stop existing timers.

Looks like you already have an instance variable to keep track of the timer, which is good.  Here is how you would create a new timer:

```
[timer invalidate]; // stop the old timer

// this timer runs once per second, perhaps you want to make it something shorter which would look less choppy
NSTimer *progressTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:progressTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
timer = progressTimer;
```

If you have a method to pause the audio, you can invalidate the timer there too.

```
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

Altogether, in your code, this would look something like:

```
 - (void)playAction:(id)sender
 {
    if([player isPlaying])
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [player pause];

        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;

    } else {

        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audiopause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [player play];

        [timer invalidate];

        NSTimer *progressTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:progressTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        timer = progressTimer;

    }

}

- (void)updateProgressBar:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSTimeInterval playTime = [self.player currentTime];
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self.player duration];
    float progress = playTime/duration;
    [_progressBar setProgress:progress];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
This is for the update slider..

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        slider.maximumValue = avAudioPlayer.duration;

        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)updateSlider {

    slider.value = avAudioPlayer.currentTime;
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

    [avAudioPlayer stop];
    [avAudioPlayer setCurrentTime:slider.value];
    [avAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [avAudioPlayer play];
}
```